# Why does <$> and <*> take input in an order opposite of >>=?

Tags: haskell, parameters, monads, functor, applicative

I understand the reasoning behind `<$>`'s type signature, as it's just an infix version of `fmap`, but comparing it to `>>=`'s type signature it makes a lot less sense to me.

Let's first establish what I mean by that.

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Looking at the type signatures we can see that `>>=` takes a value on the left, and a function on the right, which makes a lot of sense if you consider its chaining property: `foo >>= bar >>= baz`

Which leads me to wonder, why don't `<*>` and `<$>` do that too? you can't write `foo <*> bar <*> baz` because it would require the output of `foo <*> bar` to be a function, not a value.

I know that `<**>` and `=<<` exist that both flip the order of the parameters, allowing me to do something like:

```
Just 4 <**> pure (+3) <**> pure (*2) >>= (\x -> Just (x-3))
```

Which could have been beautifully reduced to:

```
Just 4 <$$> (+3) <$$> (*2) >>= (\x -> Just (x-3))
```

If `<$$>` had existed, or if the parameter order of `<$>` and `<*>` had been reversed.

Another thing that makes me wonder why the difference exists, is that it makes it harder for newcomers to get used to and/or remember whether it's the function, or the value that comes first, without having to look it up.

So why is it that in the cases of `<*>` and `<$>` it's `fn op val` but with `>>=` it's `val op fn`?

Comment: but you often want exactly this with `Applicatives`: for example `(+) <$> Just 5 <*> Just 5
` <- isn't that `Just` beautiful ;)

Comment: `(>>=)` constructs chains "imperative style" (otherwise we'd be left wondering why it isn't the same order as `$`). `(<=<)` also allows chaining - "`(.)` style". `(<*>)` is useful for "applying" multi-argument functions - supplying the arguments in the order of declaration.

Comment: The real question is why `(>>=)` is using an order opposite of pretty much everything in Haskell. The type of `(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)` looks much more like everything else in Haskell than that of `(>>=) = flip (=<<)`.

Comment: @Rhymoid I guess it's more natural to read left-to-right, so passing a value into a function left-to-right by the direction of the arrows feels more natural? `val >>= fun`

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Left-to-right, top-to-bottom is [not natural per se](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Writing_directions_of_the_world.svg). In files, "early to late" is a more appropriate terminology. In that context, it seems to make sense to have composition work like `(>>>)` does. Even the type is nicer (restricted to functions, `(>>>) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)`). To make this more natural, you also need to change how function application works: `(foo >>> bar >>> baz) x == baz (bar (foo x))`. Are you sure you want to write `x (foo >>> bar >>> baz) == ((x foo) bar) baz` instead?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Because in that case, you also get weird things like `z y x (\x y z -> ...)`. I'm not entirely sure if *mirroring* the arguments w.r.t. to the patterns *and the type* is desirable. There'll always be something unnatural in functional languages. I think having 'reversed' function composition isn't too much of a burden compared to the alternatives.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer to "why does it take parameters in this order" is basically "because". Whoever defined these functions thought that was the best way. (And it probably wasn't the same person in each case.) I will, however, offer some examples:

Suppose we have a parsing monad of some kind. Suppose also that we have defined

```
 data Foobar = Foobar X Y Z

 parseFoo :: Parser X
 parseBar :: Parser Y
 parseBaz :: Parser Z
```

Then we can write

```
 parseFoobar :: Parser Foobar
 parseFoobar = do
   foo <- parseFoo
   bar <- parseBar
   baz <- parseBaz
   return (Foobar foo bar baz)
```

Or, explicitly,

```
parseFoobar =
  parseFoo >>= \ foo ->
  parseBar >>= \ bar ->
  parseBaz >>= \ baz ->
  return (Foobar foo bar baz)
```

Now let's write that applicative-style:

```
parseFoobar = return Foobar <*> parseFoo <*> parseBar <*> parseBaz
```

or, alternatively,

```
parseFoobar = Foobar <$> parseFoo <*> parseBar <*> parseBaz
```

If we suppose that `<**> = flip <*>` exists (and has the correct associativity), then we have

```
parseFoobar = parseBaz <**> parseBar <**> parseFoo <**> return Foobar
```

That just looks strange. With the function at the end, and the arguments in reverse order? Why would you want to write it that way? (Note that any effects are *also* in reverse order.)

In the monadic version, effects happen top-to-bottom. In the applicative version, effects happen left-to-right. That seems "natural".

Comment: can you add some example types to the example functions? just so I have an easier time wrapping my head around what's happening

Comment: Edited a little stuff in.

Comment: How does this work in terms of function chaining though? what you're doing here is applying a function to 3 wrapped values, but  `Just 4 >>= foo >>= bar >>= baz`, works significantly differently from say `(+) <$> Just 3 <*> Just 4`

Comment: Rather than three "wrapped values", it's actually three _parsers_ that parse some input and produce values as output. In both versions, you're executing effectful computations (parser) that produce outputs, and then combining those outputs into a datastructure (`Foobar`).

Answer (score 22):

Don't let monads get in the way here. Think about *application.*

Compare:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

and

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

You can see there is a connection between regular application and application under a functor.

Trivia: there have been [proposals](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/idiom.html) to use brackets to overload whitespace (application) so that we can write:

```
(| f a1 .. an |)
```

instead of

```
pure f <*> a1 <*> .. <*> an
```

Comment: I never saw it like that, I only looked at `<$>` in terms of `fmap`, now that you've presented it as a variant of `$` it makes a lot more sense